Does FROST threshold signing go well with BIP340?
FROST is a popular threshold signing protocol for Schnorr-style signatures.
BIP340 is a specification for an instantiation of a Schnorr-style signature scheme for Bitcoin Taproot. Specifically, they use curve secp256k1 and make some restrictions on the point encodings.
In particular, they require in the verification algorithm that for a valid signature $(R, s)$, it holds that
point $$R = s*G - e * P$$ has an even y-coordinate.
Now, substituting $s$ and $P$ with their respective values from key generation and signing, we have $R = k * G$, where in FROST the secret nonce $k$ is a sum of nonce shares $k_i = d_i + e_i * \rho_i$.
My question is: How do we control in FROST that the point $R = k * G$ has indeed an even y-coordinate? Since, $d_i$ and $e_i$ are randomly generated, and $\rho_i$ is a hash, it seems like we can't ensure that the output signature will satisfy the required properties without having to potentially retry the signing protocol. Or am I missing something?

I think the answer is that if each party conditionally negate $d_i$, $e_i$, and the private key share during signing (depending on whether the corresponding point has even $y$ coordinate), then this will result in a valid BIP340 signature. See, for example, FROST-BIP340.

I've added some $ signs to your helpful comment so that the symbols are displayed using MathJax / $\LaTeX$.

To ensure that the point $R$ in the BIP-340 verification algorithm has even $y$-coordinate when generating signatures using the FROST threshold signing protocol, the nonce shares and the private key share need to be negated, depending on whether the common nonce commitment and the common public key, respectively, have even $y$-coordinate. This will ensure that the same condition on $R$ is met during verification.
For more details, one can also refer to the open source implementation FROST-BIP340.
